# Creating a Shell command to execute another command plus more

Tags: bash

I have a question regarding the creation of a utility that executes another command.

My script called `notify` will be placed in my /usr/local/bin directory and will do the following:

Execute the command that it was told to execute, then play a beep.

An example use case is the following:

`> notify grep -r "hard_to_find_word" /some/huge/directory/`

This is just an example, but could involve some other slower commands.

Essentially, `notify` will execute the grep, and then play a sound.

I know how to play a sound, but I do not know how to execute the provided command.

How do I execute the command that follows the call of `notify`?

Thank you for any input!

Comment: Also, don't abuse the word "function"; it has a specific meaning in bash, which neither of these are.

Comment: Sorry! I was a little confused about that but wasn't sure. So this would be more of a utility, correct?

Comment: Okay, I'll use the word command from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"$@"` is all the arguments properly separated.

```
"$@"
```

Comment: Oh! That is great! I knew that $@ provides all the parameters, but I didn't know that you could just call it by itself! Thank you!

Comment: @Kaushik , play close attention to the use of quotes here -- very important.

Comment: Hmm I tried it with and without quotes and it seems to be working the same. What do the quotes do?

Comment: The quotes make sure that arguments containing whitespace are handled properly.